# Can this R function be vectorized?

Tags: r, vectorization, conditional-statements

```
bucketIndex <- function(v, N){
  o <- rep(0, length(v))

  curSum <- 0
  index  <- 1

  for(i in seq(length(v))){
    o[i] <- index

    curSum <- curSum + v[i]
    if(curSum > N){
      curSum <- 0
      index <- index + 1
    }
  }

  o
}

> bucketIndex(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1), 3)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

I'm wondering if this function is fundamentally un-vectorizable. If it is, is there some package to deal with this "class" of functions, or is the only alternative (if I want speed) to write it as a c extension?

Comment: Does `cumsum` take care of this for you?   `curSum<-cumsum(v) ; curSum[curSum>N] <- 0 ; index<-sum(curSum == 0) `

Comment: No, that's a different function.. sum() just returns a vector of length one.

Comment: Can you comment what it should do? It is close to an integer division of the cumulative sum (`cumsum (v) %/% N`), but the complicated part is that `curSum` is set back to 0 (instead of to the modulo `cumsum (v) %% N`. See my first try towards an answer.

Comment: I want to group contiguous elements of v such that the sum within each group is >N (except possibly for the last group), and the groups have to be as small as possible (in number of elements)... but the code above is a much better description of what I want to do. The cumsum thing is close, but not the same.

Comment: Just to be clear:  does `v` exist a priori, or if we come up with a solution which draws groups of numbers in a random sampling, is that allowable?

Comment: v exists already.. my feeling for now is there's no good way to vectorize it, will probably end up closing the question with your answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say the answer is "no."   Essentially, you're changing what it is you sum over based on the results of the current sum.  This means future calculations depend on the result of an intermediate calculation, which vectorized operations can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a try (does not yet arrive at `bucketIndex`!):

- your

  ```
  curSum <- curSum + v[i]
  if(curSum > N){
    curSum <- 0
    index <- index + 1
  }
  ```

  is almost an integer division `%/%` of `cumsum (v)`.
- But not quite, your index only counts up 1 even if v [i] is > several times `N` and you start with 1. We can almost take care of that by conversion to a factor and back to integer.
- However, I'm wondering (from the name of the function) whether this behaviour is really intended:

  ```
  > bucketIndex (c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1), 3)
  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5
  > bucketIndex (c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1), 3)
  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
  ```

  I.e. just exchangig two consecutive entries in `v` can lead to different maximum in the result.
- the other point is that you count up only *after* the element that causes the sum to be > `N`. Which means that the results should have an additional 1 at the beginning and the last element should be dropped.
- You reset `curSum` to 0 regardless how much it shoots over `N`. So for all elements with `cumsum  (v) > N`, you'd need to subtract this value, then look for the next `cumsum  (v) > N` and so on. This reduces the number of loop iterations with respect to your `for` loop, but whether this gives you a substrantial improvement depends on the entries of `v` and on `N` (or, on the `max (index)` : `length (v)` ratio). If that is 50% as in your example, I don't think you can get a substantial gain. Unless there is at least an order of magnitute between them, I'd go for `inline::cfunction`.

Comment: About your third and fourth bullet points: yes, that's the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is completely vectorizable, but @cbeleites gets at one way to reduce the number of iterations in the loop by dealing with a whole chunk (bucket) at a time. Each iteration looks for where the cumulative sum exceeds `N`, assigns the index to that range, reduces the cumulative sum by whatever value was that which exceeded `N`, and repeats until the vector is exhausted. The rest is bookkeeping (initialization of value and incrementation of values).

```
bucketIndex2 <- function(v, N) {
    index <- 1
    cs <- cumsum(v)
    bk.old <- 0
    o <- rep(0, length(v))

    repeat {
        bk <- suppressWarnings(min(which(cs > N)))
        o[(bk.old+1):min(bk,length(v))] <- index
        if (bk >= length(v)) break
        cs <- cs - cs[bk]
        index <- index + 1
        bk.old <- bk
    }

    o
}
```

This matches your function for a variety of random inputs:

```
for (i in 1:200) {
  v <- sample(sample(20,1), sample(50,1)+20, replace=TRUE)
  N <- sample(10,1)
  bi <- bucketIndex(v, N)
  bi2 <- bucketIndex2(v, N)
  if (any(bi != bi2)) {
    print("MISMATCH:")
    dump("v","")
    dump("N","")
  }
}
```

Comment: bucketIndex is faster than your bucketIndex2.

Comment: @Roland I'm not particularly surprised. `which(cs>N)` is `O(n)` in the length of `v` and the repeat loop is also `O(n)` (some fraction of the length, but no better than a fraction), so the overall function should be `O(n^2)` in the length of `v`. The original function with a simple loop would be just `O(n)` in the length of `v`.